# Creating a *.bat file for switching python versions

Tags: cmd, command-line, path, environment-variables

I have two versions of python and sometimes need to switch from one environment variable to another.

I am new to standart cmd syntax but found something here however it didn't helped. Here are the contents of bat file.

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

SET PATH  = C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\Scripts;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\;
SETX PATH %PATH%

pause
```

Here cmd throws and error that 'setx' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: `set PATH = ...` sets a variable named `PATH` + _space_ to a value of _space_ + `...`, so remove the spaces around the `=`-sign...

Comment: If the `set PATH` statement worked, then you no longer have `SETX.exe` in the `PATH`. It is in `"SystemRoot%\System32"` which is often `C:\windows\System32`. Have you investigated using Python's `venv`?